# Colorizing ggplot map based on number of population

Tags: r, ggplot2, geolocation, geospatial

I have a data set including over 50,000 data. This data set includes object ,longitude and latitude (with the following structure).

```
coord <- data.frame(object = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","h","i","j","k"), LON = c(-73.95 ,-73.97,-73.95,-73.91,-73.91,-73.93,-73.96, -73.90,-73.97,-73.94),LAT =c(40.60,40.68,40.68,40.85,40.83,40.72,40.65, 40.74, 40.69, 40.82))
```

I plan to colorize different district of map. I found the below sample code.

```
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)
library(geojsonio)
library(ggplot2)
URL <- "http://services5.arcgis.com/GfwWNkhOj9bNBqoJ/arcgis/rest/services/nycd/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1=1&outFields=*&outSR=4326&f=geojson"
fil <- "nyc_community_districts.geojson"
if (!file.exists(fil)) download.file(URL, fil)
nyc_districts <- geojson_read(fil, what="sp")
nyc_districts_map <- fortify(nyc_districts, region="BoroCD")
mids <- cbind.data.frame(as.data.frame(gCentroid(nyc_districts, byid=TRUE)),id=nyc_districts$BoroCD)
gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=nyc_districts_map, map=nyc_districts_map,
                aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                color="#2b2b2b", size=0.15, fill=NA)
gg <- gg + geom_text(data=mids, aes(x=x, y=y, label=id), size=2)
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + ggthemes::theme_map()
```

Then, I used this code for colorizing different district

```
library(viridis)
# make up some fill data
set.seed(1492)
df <- data.frame(LON = c(-73.95770,-73.95445,-73.96215,-73.97739,-73.98136,-73.93974,-73.95061, -73.98609 ,-73.95724,-73.93351,-73.94931),LAT =c(40.81099,40.71415,40.71025,40.68983,40.66715,40.79821,40.66830, 40.68980, 40.71636, 40.76621, 40.80273))

pointsSp <- SpatialPoints(coords = df[,c("LON", "LAT")], 
                      proj4string = CRS(proj4string(nyc_districts)))
nyc_districts$pointCount <- 0
for(i in 1:length(nyc_districts)){
    x <- nyc_districts[i,]
    nyc_districts$pointCount[i] <- length(x[pointsSp,])
 }

choro <- data.frame(district=nyc_districts@data$BoroCD,
                fill=sample(100, nrow(nyc_districts@data)))
gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=nyc_districts_map, map=nyc_districts_map,
                aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=id),
                color="#2b2b2b", size=0.15, fill=NA)
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=choro, map=nyc_districts_map,
                aes(fill=fill, map_id=district),
                color="#2b2b2b", size=0.15) 
gg <- gg + geom_point(data=coord, aes(x=LON, y=LAT), 
                  colour= "red", alpha=1,na.rm=T)
gg <- gg + scale_fill_viridis(name="Pick ups\ndistribution") +      geom_text(data=mids, aes(x=x, y=y, label=id), size=2)
gg <- gg + coord_map()
gg <- gg + ggthemes::theme_map()
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position=c(0.1,0.5))
gg
```

In above code,with geom-point I can show the location of different coordination on the map. But my district colorization is wrong. can you please tell me how can I colorize my map based on "coord " data set.

Comment: @hrbrmstr can you please help me on this.

Comment: Will try as soon as I am home. Here I cannot access the file you want to download from the website...

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform a "Spatial Join" of the number of points intersecting each polygon. Therefore, the points have to be converted to a `SpatialPoints`Object.

```
pointsSp <- SpatialPoints(coords = coord[,c("LON", "LAT")], 
                          proj4string = CRS(proj4string(nyc_districts)))
```

Afterwards, we take each polygon of the `nyc_districts` and calculate the number of points within each.

```
nyc_districts$pointCount <- 0
for(i in 1:length(nyc_districts)){
  x <- nyc_districts[i,]
  nyc_districts$pointCount[i] <- length(pointsSp[x,])
}
```

you then just change your choro line of code to the following, which basically changes the `sample(...)` (which was there for test purposes...) to the variable we created above. Afterwards, you create the plot like you did it in your Q.

```
choro <- data.frame(district=nyc_districts@data$BoroCD,
                    fill=nyc_districts$pointCount)
```

The result looks like this: [image: result]

Comment: when I checked the legend.my legend of Pick ups distribution is between 0 and 1.

Comment: sorry, my bad. I had a mistake in my code. I changed the line `nyc_districts$pointCount[i] <- length(x[pointsSp,])`, it should work now. Let's clean up the comment session

Comment: how can I show the name of each district as legend or on the map.

Comment: First, you have to find a data set which provides the actual names of the districts. The dataset you use only provides the *BoroCD*. Either you can find a data set which provides both BoroCD and the names which you can use to join the names or you find a Spatial(point) data set which provides the names on a spatial level. The join can then be achieved by a spatial join with `[`.